# RoR: Simple no refresh on button push

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have follow and unfollow buttons for users on my application. I don't want to do anything fancy, I just want to not have the page refresh every time follow or unfollow button is clicked.

My controller

```
relationships_controller.rb

     def create
        current_user.follow(@user)
        respond_to do |format|
         format.html { #handle HTML, i.e. full page reload }
         format.js # handle ajax request
        end
      end
    
      def destroy
        current_user.unfollow(@user)
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html
          format.js # this one handle the request comes from `remote: true` button
        end
      end
```

My view

```
tweets/index.html.erb

    <% if current_user.id != tweet.user.id %> 
                <% if current_user.following?(tweet.user) %>
                  <%= button_to "Unfollow", relationships_path(user_id: tweet.user), remote: true, method: :delete, :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
                 <% else %>
                   <%= button_to "Follow", relationships_path(user_id: tweet.user), remote: true, :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
                <% end %>
                <br>
               <% end %>
               <hr/>
              <% end %>
```

Relationships model

```
relationship.rb

class Relationship < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"

    validates :follower_id, presence: true
    validates :followed_id, presence: true
end
```

User model

```
User.rb

has_many :active_relationships, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :passive_relationships, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: "followed_id", dependent: :destroy


  has_many :following, through: :active_relationships, source: :followed
  has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower


  def follow(user)
    active_relationships.create(followed_id: user.id)
  end

  def unfollow(user)
    active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: user.id).destroy
  end

  def following?(user)
    following.include?(user)
  end
```

Routes

```
routes.rb
    resource :relationships, :only => [:create, :destroy]
```

Application.js

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("chartkick")
require("chart.js")

//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

Inspected button element

```
<form class="button_to" method="post" action="/relationships?user_id=1" data-remote="true"><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Follow"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="hfwF8wXBcp/OM2P/pCYBnEBrjw22BDKWbw/dZFwwDsRpiIFq5jBKS/AoTMjkCZRrGum7UyW1kaL3h/4XEM2wIg=="></form>
```

With this when I click follow nothing now happens. I think I need a new js file in my views but unsure how to implement it.

I have looked at solutions but they are many and varied and seeking to do more than I want to do which is just a simple no refresh.

How is this best achieved? (can provide more code if needed)

EDIT: This code got jQuery working in Rails 6 in my ..webpack/enironment.js file

```
# app/config/webpack/environment.js
const {environment} = require('@rails/webpacker');

const webpack = require('webpack');
environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery' # or if its not work specify path `'jquery/src/jquery'` which node_modules path for jquery
}));

module.exports = environment;
```

For @max

```
  $(document).on('ajax:success', '.follow-btn', function(event){
  let $el = $(this);
  let method = this.dataset.method;
  if (method === 'post') {
    $('.follow-btn[href="'+this.href+'"]').each(function(el){ $(el).text('Unfollow');  });
    this.dataset.method = 'delete';
  } else if (method === 'delete') {
    $('.follow-btn[href="'+this.href+'"]').each(function(el){ $(el).text('Follow');  });
    this.dataset.method = 'post';
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the `<button>` element in your browser to make sure the `data-remote="true"` attribute is being set? Also, can you post your javascript manifest? You would need to be using `jquery` and `ujs` for the remote option to have an effect.

Comment: Added both to question. 'data-remote="true"' appears to be set

Comment: Ok so now it is actually working BUT I want the follow button to change to unfollow on the button click (see my view above). Right now nothing happens in the view. If I refresh the unfollow button comes up though which means the follow action works but I need it to just change to unfollow without refresh

Comment: You're going to have to write some JavaScript to change the state of the button. This is beyond the scope of your original question, but you'll need to create `.js.erb` files for the respective controller actions and change the state based on the response from your controller. It's involved.

Comment: OK thanks, this seems more complicated than I thought. I'll ask a new question later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of going down the `js.erb` rabbit hole you can just send a JSON request and write a simple event handler.

Lets start by adding a [`data-type="json"`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#data-type) attribute to the buttons so they send a request for JSON instead of javascript:

```
<% unless current_user == tweet.user %> 
  <% if current_user.following?(tweet.user) %>
    <%= link_to "Unfollow", relationships_path(user_id: tweet.user), 
        data: { remote: true, type: :json, method: :delete }, 
        class: "follow-btn btn btn-primary" 
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to "Follow", relationships_path(user_id: tweet.user), 
        data: { remote: true, type: :json, method: :post}, 
        class: "follow-btn btn btn-primary" 
    %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And then just write JSON responses for your controller.

```
def create
  current_user.follow(@user)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { head :created }
  end
end
    
def destroy
  current_user.unfollow(@user)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

As you can see its pretty damn simple, when creating a resource you return a  `201 - Created` and usually a location header or the entity in the body (a JSON payload describing what was created). When you update or destroy a record a  `204 - No Content` status code is sufficient.

If you test it now and look at the network tab in your browser inspector you will see that an AJAX request is sent but nothing happens in the view.

So lets write an event handler that toggles the button text and method after the request was sent. Since Rails UJS already created the AJAX handler for the button for us we can just [hook into its events](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#rails-ujs-event-handlers):

```
// put this in your application.js or anywhere in your pack
$(document).on('ajax:success', '.follow-btn', function(event){
  let $el = $(this);
  let method = this.dataset.method;
  if (method === 'post') {
    $el.text('Unfollow');
    this.dataset.method = 'delete';
  } else if (method === 'delete') {
    $el.text('Follow');
    this.dataset.method = 'post';
  }
});
```

### Why is this better than a js.erb template?

- No server side involvement in updating the UI on the client. No spagetti-code views.
- JavaScript is minified, not generated by ERB and easy to debug/reason about.
- It can be changed to use optimistic create/delete to give instant feedback

Comment: This is a simplified example that lacks error handling - you should expect edge cases where creating the relationship fails and adjust according.

Comment: thanks for that. Much appreciated. I'm getting this error Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at Object../app/javascript/packs/application.js (application.js:28)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:83
    at bootstrap:83

Comment: Got it working, thank you so much. For Rails 6 I added some code to webpack/environment. js. I'd love it to also automatically update counts in the view on the button click but I guess that is for another day :) Thank you.

Comment: That's a separate question but you can do it by returning a count (as JSON) in the response body from rails and reading it through ‘event.details[0]’ in your event handler and changing the text/element. When deleting the resource use 200 - OK instead.

Comment: Can I just ask one final question related to your right answer? I have the tweets listed out as <% @tweets.reverse.each do |tweet| %>... but the follow button only changes for first on the list...leaves the rest as is (they can't be used too). Is there a way to make them all change? It would be perfect if there was. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, select all the elements you want to change and loop through them and change the text. Something like `$('.follow-btn[href="'+this.href+'"]').each(function(el){ $(el).text('New text');  });` would update all the links that point to the same user. When writing the code I actually specifically targeted the element the user clicked to avoid side-effects.

Comment: You mean like this?  $(document).on('ajax:success', '.follow-btn', function(event){
  let $el = $(this);
  let method = this.dataset.method;
  if (method === 'post') {
    $('.follow-btn[href="'+this.href+'"]').each(function(el){ $(el).text('Unfollow');  });
    this.dataset.method = 'delete';
  } else if (method === 'delete') {
    $('.follow-btn[href="'+this.href+'"]').each(function(el){ $(el).text('Follow');  });
    this.dataset.method = 'post';
  }
});         The buttons work but no changes in the view?

Comment: I put the code in the question temporarily (forgot to format)

Comment: Do you think you could ask this as a separate question instead? It's hard to do follow up via comments

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63207894/ror-and-json-no-refresh-on-button-click-and-updating-count  I started a new question here. Thanks for the help. Really appreciated.