# RoR and json: No refresh on button click and updating count

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json

I am trying to get follow buttons to change without refreshing the page on click. The following code works but only for the first post in the loop I am rendering in the view. The rest don't change/work.

In my view

```
<% @tweets.reverse.each do |tweet| %>
...
<% if current_user.id != tweet.user.id %> 
        <% if current_user.following?(tweet.user) %>
          <%= link_to "Unfollow", relationships_path(user_id: tweet.user), data: { remote: true, type: :json, method: :delete }, :class => "follow-btn btn btn-primary" %>
         <% else %>
           <%= link_to "Follow", relationships_path(user_id: tweet.user), data: { remote: true, type: :json, method: :post }, :class => "follow-btn btn btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
        <br>
       <% end %>
       <hr/>
      <% end %>
<% end %>
```

application.js

```
$(document).on('ajax:success', '.follow-btn', function(event){
  let $el = $(this);
  let method = this.dataset.method;
  if (method === 'post') {
    $el.text('Unfollow');
    this.dataset.method = 'delete';
  } else if (method === 'delete') {
    $el.text('Follow');
    this.dataset.method = 'post';
  }
});
```

How can I make it to update all the follow buttons that point to the same user in the loop?

Here is the newer code

```
application.js

$(document).on('ajax:success', '.follow-btn', function(event){
  let $el = $(this);
  let method = this.dataset.method;
  if (method === 'post') {
    $('.follow-btn[href="'+this.href+'"]').each(function(el){ $(el).text('Unfollow');  });
    this.dataset.method = 'delete';
  } else if (method === 'delete') {
    $('.follow-btn[href="'+this.href+'"]').each(function(el){ $(el).text('Follow');  });
    this.dataset.method = 'post';
  }
});
```

Controller

```
def create
    current_user.follow(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { head :created }
    end
  end

  def destroy
    current_user.unfollow(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

Here the buttons still work but now don't change in the view. How can I get this to work?

**Count**

On the same view but rendered through a partial (users/_search_users.html.erb) I count like so. How can I make it so this count also updates without page refresh on button click?

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
...
    <td stlye="padding:0 60px 0 60px;" col width="130" align="right"><b><%= user.followers.count %> Followers</b></td>
<% end %>
```

I'd like to get both the button and count to update on click without refresh. I can add more code if needed.

ty

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple questions rolled into one.

Comment: Thanks! Strange, it does not work for some reason. The button works but nothing at all happens now on the view. I see it's working on your snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('ajax:success', '.follow-btn', function(e) {
  // the JSON fetched
  let data = e.details[0];
  // the method we are changing to
  let method = this.dataset.method === 'post' ? 'delete' : 'post';
  // lookup table for the text
  let txt = {
    post: 'Follow',
    delete: 'Unfollow'
  }[method];
  // loop through elements with the same href
  $(`.follow-btn[href="${this.getAttribute('href')}"]`).each(function() {
    // change the attributes of the single node in the loop
    this.dataset.method = method;
    $(this).text(`${txt} (${data.count})`);
  });
});

// This mocks the ajax call purely for the sake of this stacksnippets example.
// Do not include this in your actual implementation
$(document).on('click', 'a[data-remote]', function(e) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    let event = jQuery.Event('ajax:success');
    event.details = [{ count: 5 }, 'No Content'];
    $(e.target).trigger(event);
  }, 25);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>User 1</p>
  <a href="/follow/1" class="follow-btn" data-method="post" data-remote="true">Follow</a>
  <a href="/follow/1" class="follow-btn" data-method="post" data-remote="true">Follow</a>
</div>
<div>
  <p>User 2</p>
  <a href="/follow/2" class="follow-btn" data-method="post" data-remote="true">Follow</a>
  <a href="/follow/2" class="follow-btn" data-method="post" data-remote="true">Follow</a>
</div>
```

You can provide counts in the JSON responses by using `render json:`:

```
def create
    current_user.follow(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json do
        render json: { count: @user.followers.count }, 
               status: :created  
      end
    end
  end

def destroy
  current_user.unfollow(@user)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json do
        render json: { count: @user.followers.count }, 
               status: :ok
    end
  end
end
```

I'm just guessing the association so adjust according to your models.

Comment: Thanks, for the first snippet for the button I get error in the console "cannot read property '0' of undefined"?

Comment: Thats wierd. I fixed a bug - need to use `this.getAttribute('href')` instead of `this.href` as the later returns the absolute path.

Comment: Oh i'm nearly there but still getting the "cannot read property '0' error". If I leave out the count the button works, just the text won't change.

Comment: Ah, sorry my bad. Its `e.detail`. Not `.details`. No idea why they went with that super weird signature in Rails 5.1. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#rails-ujs-event-handlers

Comment: Ok some success! the buttons are changing but i'm getting "(undefined)" in brackets next to "Follow/unfollow" on the buttons after clicking? I assume this is to do with the count.

Comment: thank you so much, I got it working by removing the rendering of the count from the button. Can I just render that count somewhere else? I was not going to put it on the button. Thanks for the assistance there and hopefully it will be of use to others. really appreciated :)

Comment: Yeah, its just a string and you can attach it to the DOM in any number of ways. See https://api.jquery.com/append/